# Twitter+OAuth still giving me warnings

Tags: iphone, twitter-oauth

Its installed and working but I still get 10 warnings. Is this because the engine is out of date and not 100% compatible with new support libraries? has anyone manage to ge this installed clean with no warnings please share your sources.

I based my installation on "Mark Hammonds on Sep 22nd 2010 " tutorial.

WARNNINGS:

```
/xCode_Projects/Official Apps/WnS/APP/WnS/WnS/Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMessagesParser.m
'MGTwitterStatusesParser' may not respond to '-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'
'MGTwitterStatusesParser' may not respond to '-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'
file://localhost/xCode_Projects/Official%20Apps/WnS/APP/WnS/WnS/Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMessagesParser.m: warning: Semantic Issue: 'MGTwitterStatusesParser' may not respond to 'parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'

/xCode_Projects/Official Apps/WnS/APP/WnS/WnS/Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMiscParser.m
'MGTwitterStatusesParser' may not respond to '-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'
'MGTwitterStatusesParser' may not respond to '-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'
/xCode_Projects/Official Apps/WnS/APP/WnS/WnS/Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterStatusesParser.m
'MGTwitterXMLParser' may not respond to '-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'
'MGTwitterXMLParser' may not respond to '-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'
/xCode_Projects/Official Apps/WnS/APP/WnS/WnS/Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterUsersParser.m
'MGTwitterStatusesParser' may not respond to '-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'
'MGTwitterStatusesParser' may not respond to '-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'
/xCode_Projects/Official Apps/WnS/APP/WnS/WnS/Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterXMLParser.m
Class 'MGTwitterXMLParser' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol
Class 'MGTwitterXMLParser' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol
```

Comment: Solved. Turns out the folder did need to be at the root of the project. Had it in a "external libs" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Turns out the folder needed to be at the root of the project. I Had it in a "external libs" folder.